# Implement a triangle between views (like the one on Instagram login screen)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uiimageview

I would like to know if there is an easy/elegent way to implement a triange between views (like the one you may see on Instagram login screen). See screenshot attached.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `UIView` with `backgroundColor` set to white. Add a 45° rotation with

```
caretView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_4))
```

Comment: Geniously simple and just what I needed! Much appreciated!